# parsing proxy adress with Regex and python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, proxy

I'm trying to retrieve the address of a proxy by parsing a string that contains the ip and the port buried in a lot of useless text.
After a lot of unsuccessful attempts, I started looking into the regex.

```
def parseLine(line):
stock = []
listpat = ["\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", "^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d\d|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)$ "] #ip, port

for elem in line:
    for pat in listpat:
        result = re.match(pat, elem)
        if result:
            stock.append(result)

with open('list.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for cell in stock:
        writer.writerows(cell)
```

the two regex are respectively the paterns for an IP and for the port.
Here's an example of the string I'm researching :

```
<tr class="odd"><td><input id="row1" name="c1" onclick="choice()" type="checkbox" value="2057281.204.168.1069921863141"/></td><td>201.204.168.106<script type="text/javascript">document.write(":"+t+w+q+p+q)</script></td><td>high-anonymous</td><td><dfn title="01:09:16 AM GMT">Jun-19-2020</dfn></td><td>Costa Rica</td><td class="organization">San Antonio De Belen</td></tr>
```

the only information I'm interested in are

> 201.204.168.106

> the result of `<script type="text/javascript">document.write(":"+t+w+q+p+q)</script>`

what are my mistakes?

Comment: Use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`, the latter binds the expression to the very start of the string (which is `<tr...>` in your example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `re.search() / re.findall()` rather than `re.match()`. The latter binds the expression to the start of the string where it cannot find any address. See the following working code:

```
import re

string = """
<tr class="odd"><td><input id="row1" name="c1" onclick="choice()" type="checkbox" value="2057281.204.168.1069921863141"/></td><td>201.204.168.106<script type="text/javascript">document.write(":"+t+w+q+p+q)</script></td><td>high-anonymous</td><td><dfn title="01:09:16 AM GMT">Jun-19-2020</dfn></td><td>Costa Rica</td><td class="organization">San Antonio De Belen</td></tr>
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)')

for possible_ip in rx.findall(string):
    print(possible_ip)
```

Which yields

```
201.204.168.106
```

Comment: that's weird, this solution don't work on my side ... I have to check few things to be sure.

Comment: my problem was that my String was not recognized as such.  the addition of the str() function allowed to correct